# ElasticSearch Jest client, how to return document id from hit?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I'm using Jest as ElasticSearch client to search documents:

```
JestClient client = ...;
Search search = ...;
SearchResult searchResult = client.execute(search);
List<Hit<T, Void>> hits = searchResult.getHits(klass);
```

Each `Hit` object looks like:

`{"_index":"some_index","_type":"some_type","_id":"some_id","_score":2.609438,"_source":{"foo1":"bar1","foo2":"bar2"}}`

While I can only find `hit.source` method, it seems no `hit.id` method.

Parse it as JSON object and retrieve key `_id`'s value is a way, but is there any API that can get the document id?

Comment: if you add an id to your Class klass using annotation `@JestId` it should be mapped directly

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just fyi, was looking for same so took a look at Jest source code and saw that Jest does populate hit.source.es_metadata_id with the "_id" if it exists (see io.searchbox.core.SearchResult, line 115)

So could do something like following as alternative to annotation:

```
List<Hit<Map,Void>> hits = client.execute(search).getHits(Map.class)
Hit hit = hits.get(0)
Map source = (Map)hit.source
String id = (String)source.get(JestResult.ES_METADATA_ID)
```

Answer (score 6):

It seems no way to get `_id` via `Jest` API, have to get `_id` from `_source` object.

As @juliendangers mentioned, add `@JestId` annotation can achieve:

```
public class MyClass {
    @JestId private String documentId;
    private String foo;
}
```

And must explicitly set document id:
`myClass.setDocumentId("some_id");`

Each `Hit` object looks like:
`{"_index":"some_index","_type":"some_type","_id":"some_id","_score":2.609438,"_source":{"foo":"bar","documentId":"some_id"}}`

(If not explicitly set document id, the `"documentId":"some_id"` pair will be missing from `Hit`)

While according to my test, if use inheritance, have to explicitly set parent class's document id:

```
public class ParentClass {
    @JestId private String documentId;
}

public class MyClass extends ParentClass {
    private String foo;
    public MyClass() {
        super.setDocumentId("some_id");
    }
}
```